# Eclipse/Android/NFC - Cannot Resolve to a Type while following a Tutorial?

Tags: android, eclipse

(First of all - there have been a topic with similar title before, but about a different situation.)

First of all - I am not a Java programmer. I am a Unity Developer only with expereience with Unity scripts. I am trying to implement NFC reading into an Android Game. I am following [THIS](https://tapintonfc.org/2014/11/developer-tip-how-to-use-nfc-with-unity-3d-in-android-devices/) tutorial but have encountered a wild error.

In all code provided in the link I have to change the company name (twinsprite) and the project name because I will need it for more then one app and the same name would collide in multiple copies in our files. Still, when I tried doing that, an error occured when I tried to "Run as Ant Build" the build.xml file: "NfcF cannot be resolved to a type".

It's stated to be in this code, line:

`techListsArray = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcF.class.getName() } };`

Full code below:

```
package com.aiorai.sciezkaedukacyjna;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap;
import com.google.common.primitives.Bytes;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
public class SciezkaEdukacyjnaTest extends UnityPlayerActivity {

public static final String MIME_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";

private static final BiMap URI_PREFIX_MAP = ImmutableBiMap.builder()
        .put((byte) 0x00, "")
        .put((byte) 0x01, "http://www.")
        .put((byte) 0x02, "https://www.")
        .put((byte) 0x03, "http://")
        .put((byte) 0x04, "https://")
        .put((byte) 0x05, "tel:")
        .put((byte) 0x06, "mailto:")
        .put((byte) 0x07, "ftp://anonymous:anonymous@")
        .put((byte) 0x08, "ftp://ftp.")
        .put((byte) 0x09, "ftps://")
        .put((byte) 0x0A, "sftp://")
        .put((byte) 0x0B, "smb://")
        .put((byte) 0x0C, "nfs://")
        .put((byte) 0x0D, "ftp://")
        .put((byte) 0x0E, "dav://")
        .put((byte) 0x0F, "news:")
        .put((byte) 0x10, "telnet://")
        .put((byte) 0x11, "imap:")
        .put((byte) 0x12, "rtsp://")
        .put((byte) 0x13, "urn:")
        .put((byte) 0x14, "pop:")
        .put((byte) 0x15, "sip:")
        .put((byte) 0x16, "sips:")
        .put((byte) 0x17, "tftp:")
        .put((byte) 0x18, "btspp://")
        .put((byte) 0x19, "btl2cap://")
        .put((byte) 0x1A, "btgoep://")
        .put((byte) 0x1B, "tcpobex://")
        .put((byte) 0x1C, "irdaobex://")
        .put((byte) 0x1D, "file://")
        .put((byte) 0x1E, "urn:epc:id:")
        .put((byte) 0x1F, "urn:epc:tag:")
        .put((byte) 0x20, "urn:epc:pat:")
        .put((byte) 0x21, "urn:epc:raw:")
        .put((byte) 0x22, "urn:epc:")
        .put((byte) 0x23, "urn:nfc:").build();

private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

IntentFilter[] mIntentFilter;

String[][] techListsArray;

private static String value = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Foreground Dispatch: 1. Creates a PendingIntent object so the Android system can populate it with the details of the tag when it is scanned.
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SciezkaEdukacyjnaTest.this, 0,
            new Intent(SciezkaEdukacyjnaTest.this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    // Foreground Dispatch: 2. Declare intent filters to handle the intents that you want to intercept 
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter[] { new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED) };
    // Foreground Dispatch: 3. Set up an array of tag technologies that your application wants to handle.
    techListsArray = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcF.class.getName() } };

    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
        Log.e(SciezkaEdukacyjnaTest.class.toString(), "This device doesn't support NFC.");
        finish();
        return;
    }
    if (!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Log.e(SciezkaEdukacyjnaTest.class.toString(), "NFC is disabled.");
    } else {
        Log.i(SciezkaEdukacyjnaTest.class.toString(), "NFC reader initialized.");
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Enables the foreground dispatch when the activity regains focus.
    mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, mIntentFilter, techListsArray);
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Disables the foreground dispatch when the activity loses focus.
    mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    if (tag != null) {
        // Parses through all NDEF messages and their records and picks text and uri type.
        Parcelable[] data = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        String s = "";
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    NdefRecord[] recs = ((NdefMessage) data[i]).getRecords();
                    for (int j = 0; j < recs.length; j++) {
                        if (recs[j].getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN
                                && Arrays.equals(recs[j].getType(), NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT)) {
                            /*
                            * See NFC forum specification for
                            * "Text Record Type Definition" at 3.2.1
                            * 
                            * http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/
                            * 
                            * bit_7 defines encoding bit_6 reserved for
                            * future use, must be 0 bit_5..0 length of IANA
                            * language code
                            */
                            byte[] payload = recs[j].getPayload();
                            String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 0200) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
                            int langCodeLen = payload[0] & 0077;
                            s += new String(payload, langCodeLen + 1, payload.length - langCodeLen - 1,
                                    textEncoding);
                        } else if (recs[j].getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN
                                && Arrays.equals(recs[j].getType(), NdefRecord.RTD_URI)) {
                            /*
                            * See NFC forum specification for
                            * "URI Record Type Definition" at 3.2.2
                            * 
                            * http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/
                            * 
                            * payload[0] contains the URI Identifier Code
                            * payload[1]...payload[payload.length - 1]
                            * contains the rest of the URI.
                            */
                            byte[] payload = recs[j].getPayload();
                            String prefix = (String) URI_PREFIX_MAP.get(payload[0]);
                            byte[] fullUri = Bytes.concat(prefix.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")),
                                    Arrays.copyOfRange(payload, 1, payload.length));
                            s += new String(fullUri, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                value = e.getMessage();
                Log.e(SciezkaEdukacyjnaTest.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        Log.i(SciezkaEdukacyjnaTest.class.toString(), s);
        value = s;
    }
}
public static String getValue() {
    return value;
}
}
```

As an absolute non-Javer, I am quite puzzled. What exorcisms have to be performed to repel this error?